# How to shave down or flatten - surface concrete of garage - rain water leaking in under door

Tags: floor, garage, flooding, leveling

I have a garage floor - the floor in the garage has sunken leaving the area at the exterior foundation wall - Entrance - to sit up higher like a nice ramp which makes a perfect Rain Water collection scoop to wonderfully force the water under the door and into the garage (if anyone wanted to know how that was done - there is your answer.) So I am looking for a way to fix this problem - I thought about grinding and shaving at the Garage Floor to Drive way to even it out with the garage floor and prevent it from acting like a funnel - I have done all kinds of things to seal the door - they have helped reduce the pond in the garage but not end the flow..

Here is a drawing :
[image: Garage Floor in Black/Blue - Garage Door in Brown, Drive way in Green Blue Area is what I want to level out and even up - it is 16 feet wide by 4 inches. I prefer not to fill my garage with leveler - but maybe that is the right or only way ..]

Actual Picture - May not show it correctly maybe I should have used a level or an angle gauge to display the angle of the slant..
[image: Garage Door and Base at entrance]

Comment: Mud-jacking might be possible, get your garage floor back to level.

Comment: @HartCO -I thought on Mud Jacking - looking at price and what I will end up with versus leveling - each has pros and cons - and I was looking at rent a machine skin that surface 1/2 inch and voila ..but I think the things I don't want is the things it will need .

Comment: cut a slit from the garage door to the driveway at the deepest point to drain the buildup before it seeps.

Answer (score 2):

When faced with a similar problem I opted to cut the blue part about 4 inches away from the garage slab, break and remove the concrete, and put in a pre fabricated French drain. The cutting was done with an old skilsaw and $15 diamond blade, and busting was with hand tools. About a 1 day project.[image]

Comment: Your drain looks like it is on the outside of the garage not the garage floor slab - mine is part of the house slab - so I am not too sure on doing this - although I think it looks appealing from a $ money stand point. And based on the other answers so far - I will investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I’d be concerned with grinding, shaving, or otherwise removing material from actual driveway.  It would weaken the slab, which you drive on, I assume, and there is no guarantee that the garage floor won’t sink more over time anyway.  That solution seems more like a gypsy-rigging than anything else.  But if anything, build up the garage floor inside the door…it will mean a speed bump of sorts, but that is better than removing thickness from the drive, IMO

It is not directly answering the specific question you asked, but since it is the sinking of the garage floor that has been the source of the problem, have you considered having it poly-jacked back to its appropriate height?

Comment: I considered having it jacked but I was looking at expense - the less I can sink into this house the better . Which is why I was not going the leveling route .. I did think on the grinding - I am removing material. Fixing the flooring - leveling might be my only real option as mud jacking - is not perfect either and leveler will cover the defects from the sinking..

Answer (score 0):

How wide is the area that is "scooping" the water? If it's just an inch or two, you could install a "custom door bottom shoe" similar to this:

https://www.google.com/shopping/product/17539833447353702067?q=pemko+door+sweeps&client=mobilesearchapp&rlz=1MDAPLB_enUS552US552&hl=en&channel=iss&v=30.1.161623614&noj=1&biw=375&bih=495&dpr=2&tch=6&wf=pp1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi81M6YsfvVAhXHPCYKHYVwBEgQ8wIIkQEwEg

Or this:

http://www.mrlock.com/pemko-210dv-36-door-shoe?language=en&currency=USD&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_o7NBRDgARIsAKvAgt3N3hmFx7_hVqaPKIVzD2FVBqEI4UMC1JPzQeuKNGZBliKHYynv_lwaAhUUEALw_wcB

You just need to make the "skirting" wide enough to cover the scoop, but it will only be as good as the outer seal.

Comment: I have done these things to the door and then some - I have the bottom seal and I have an additional sweep , I have tried adjusting the door down and I have tried to place things down behind the door to keep the rain water out. 4 inches in front of the door from outside (higher elevation) to garage angled down towards garage interior lower elevation. about a 1 inch drop in 4 inches distance.